# Placed over special UI, but special UI appears through (unclickable)

Tags: gtk, x11, gdk

I opened a new window, I made it fullscreen and then set it to always on top with `XSendEvent` on `_NET_WM_STATE` to set `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` and then I `XFlush`'ed. This makes the window appear on top of everything this is great.

Aside: I then draw the screenshot of the desktop to that window and overlay it with a 50% opacity black transparent layer.

So now the issue I am having is that placement is right and it is correct in that it is over the special UI (dock and menu bar) in that you cannot click it. But when I click in the window, the special UI just *appears* through. You cannot click on it, it is just appearing above my window.

Is there any window properties I can set to fix this issue?

## Here is a screenshot showing before I click in the window:

[image]

## Here is screenshot showing after i click in the window, the special ui appears through (while not clickable - which is good)

[image]

## Replication

I can replicate this situation exactly on your system. Its a released firefox addon. Let me know please and we can chat using stackoverflow and i can walk you through to replicate.

Comment: Could you try with a very simple fullscreen window, e.g. calling [gtk_window_fullscreen](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-fullscreen) on an empty GTK+ window? If it has the same problem then it's likely the WM's fault.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesSasongko I'll test out and report back :)